# Change ListView Cell color in Android Custom Them

Tags: android, listview, themes, drawable

I need to change cellselector color in whole app. I defined my custom Theme, but I can't recognize which attribute I should change to do what I need.

Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set attribute in your list selector is simply selector xml in your drawable:

```
list:android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```